# Why do I get the same result when I fetch the rotated image's width and height?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm getting the same width and height even the image is rotated. Why does this occur?

```
from PIL import Image

with Image.open("pic.jpg") as im:
    rotated_90 = im.rotate(90)
    print(rotated_90.size, "\t", rotated_90.width, rotated_90.height)

    rotated_180 = im.rotate(180)
    print(rotated_180.size, "\t", rotated_180.width, rotated_180.height)

    rotated_270 = im.rotate(270)
    print(rotated_270.size, "\t", rotated_270.width, rotated_270.height)
```

```
(1049, 590)      1049 590
(1049, 590)      1049 590
(1049, 590)      1049 590
```

Comment: Try to add argument `expand=True` to the `rotate` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
rotated_90 = im.rotate(90, expand=1)
```

Pillow will only change the dimensions of the image if you add expand=1 to the arguments, or else it will only rotate the image from the center.